# Preposition preceding a verb

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, grammar-identification, preposition, word-order

i came across this sentence in Orberg's book:

"Quid inest in saccis?"

Or

"Ecce iulius ad villam advenit."

My question is that why there are aditional prepositions, namely another "in" and "ad", where there is one attached to the verb?

Is it possible without the preposition? Can i not say:
Quid est in saccis?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I thought this question seemed familiar and it turns out it is - I [asked the same thing](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12858/5056) when I reached that chapter in LLSPI. :)

Comment: @adam interesting;Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can say "Quid est in saccis," but also "Quid inest saccis?" In that case it's the dative. The Romans used *inesse* in both ways.