# On the (necessary or typical?) relationship between double accusative and causation

Tags: verbs, syntax, morphology, accusative, semantics

I was wondering if there is a syntactic/semantic generalization that can account for the so-called "double accusative" predicative frame in Latin (verbs with person & thing (*docere pueros grammaticam*) & complex verbs with the preverb *trans-* (*transducere exercitum Rhenum*)). Looking at the [data1](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bennett.html#sect178) & [data2](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/double-accusatives), it seems that the verb is necessarily (*or only typically?*) **causative**: i.e., 'someone1 **causes** someone2 {to have/acquire} something'; 'someone1 **causes** someone2 to go somewhere, etc.}'. One advantage of this causation-based proposal is that it can account for the fact that in the passive construction, which involves *de*motion of 'someone1', only the hierarchically superior object (i.e. 'someone2') can be the subject, the third nominal phrase (i.e. 'something') being too low in the structure to be *pro*moted to the subject of a passive. This causation-based generalization would, for example, also prevent stative verbs from taking two accusative objects/nominal phrases.

So my question is the following one: Are there exceptions to this connection between **double accusative** (i.e. two objects/nominal phrases in accusative) and **causation**? I'd like to know if **this connection is necessary or only (proto)typical**. If the answer is the second one, could you please provide some examples that involve non-causative verbs?

One potential problem for the abovementioned generalization is that the causative meaning is not typically expressed, although some authors do have established a connection between *-o-* vocalism and causation (e.g., *d**o**cere* as the causative verb of *discere*; *r**o**gare* as the causative verb of *regere*; *m**o**nere* as the causative verb of *meminisse*: e.g. see [Rubio (1982: 127)](https://vdocuments.mx/lisardo-rubio-introduccion-a-la-sintaxis-estructural-del-latin.html)). Although there appears to be no morphological reflex of that connection in most of verbs (see [data1](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bennett.html#sect178) & [data2](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/double-accusatives)), this does not mean that the generalization cannot be established in a more abstract way (i.e. the verb can be decomposed into (sub)events: the causative one and the subordinate one).

Comment: I feel like you're using "causative" in too broad a way. *Transducere* absolutely isn't a causative in the way *docere* and *monere* are/were (they're not really meaningfully causatives in Latin but they descend from true PIE causatives), and I don't really see how it's any more "causative" than just *ducere*, which only takes a single accusative. Maybe I'm just missing your point.

Comment: @Cairnarvon The theoretical claim here is that those verbs that take two accusatives are complex in the sense that they involve a causative verbal layer that can assign accusative case to the person object. In the passive, it is only this upper causative verb that lacks its accusative case assigning property. In technical terms, the person object has "structural" accusative case, while the thing object receives "inherent/lexical" accusative case.

Comment: @Cairnarvon The passive construction absorbs the structural case assigned by the upper causative verbal layer, but crucially not the lexical one assigned by the inner predicate (e.g. the V _discere_ in the case of _docere_ or the P _trans_- in the case of _transducere_).

Comment: @Cairnarvon As for your natural objection "you're using 'causative' in too broad a way", it's true that lexical causative verbs are typically defined as those ones that enter into the so-called "causative alternation" (e.g., the Latin verb _lenire_. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative_alternation ). In the more general sense used here, causative verbs are all the ones affected by the so-called "Event Composition Rule": e = e1 → e2 : e consists of two subevents, e1, e2 such that e1 causally implicates e2 ( https://dingo.sbs.arizona.edu/~hharley/courses/PDF/HaleAndKeyser1993.pdf).

Comment: @Cairnarvon As for the difference between _transducere_ and _ducere_, it is important to realize that only the former involves an additional resultative subevent (introduced by the "satellite" _trans_-”: cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11083/are-latin-verbs-of-motion-satellite-framed-or-verb-framed ). A similar parallelism is found in English: cf. _bring_ vs. _bring_ + _across_. The former involves a simple event structure (only the activity subeventuality is involved), whereas the latter involves a complex event structure, i.e., a **causative** one (activity (e1) + result (e2)).

Comment: @Cairnarvon For useful detailed discussion of these ideas applied to Latin, please see https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-morphosyntax-of-transitions-9780198733287?cc=es&lang=en&