# "Puella per portās urbis ducta est." Why is est added to the end of this sentence?

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation

I'm a Latin beginner and I'm using a book called "so you really want to learn Latin", and they give a Latin sentence as below:
**Puella per portās urbis ducta est**.

My question is I don't understand why 'est' is added to the end — 'est' should be the 3rd person singular form of the verb "to be", but isn't the verb here just 'ducta'? If I translated the sentence without 'est', it would be "The girl was led through the gates of the city", right? Thus I don't see how "est" can possibly change this sentence.

Apologies if I am being wordy here.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Does it make more sense to you if you use the passive participle form of _ducere_?

Comment: Is that the P.P.P form? Ok I think I get what you mean with the help of an example on my book, but is there a reason the form of the verb "to be" has to be added? Or is it just something that goes with the perfect passive tense?

Comment: This is the first question in the history of this site to be answered by all four moderators and nobody else.

Comment: Wow very cool, but anyways thanks everyone! My question is solved :)

Comment: @sheepscholar If your question is solved, don't forget to upvote and mark as ✓ the one you feel answered it best.

Comment: I've just seen that the author of the textbook you mention (_So you really want to learn Latin_) has some interesting material in youtube for learners of Latin. The particular sentence you're interested in is discussed at 11:06 in this videoclip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrG1DWrM5Xg  Don't miss his funny song at 4:49!

Comment: @Mitomino: I learned Latin from Nicholas-Oulton's series-of-three books and have quoted from them.  Most notably, his teachings on the gerund/ gerundive.  (On CHAT there has just been an interesting debate on active/ passive translations of gerundive "serviendum", which might interest yourself.) Linked to  Mr. Oulton's three texts is "Latin Translations" by Betty Halifax. A delightful work in which tales from Roman mythology are written in elementary Latin.

Comment: @tony Thanks for this information. Mr. Oulton seems to be a very motivated teacher (I took a look at some of his interesting videoclips at https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5P-g7uXmTfMVWCxhzIZy_g ). It's very important to have teachers who really love their subject and he seems to be one of them. So I'm sure you made a very good decision in learning Latin from his books.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just to put succinctly what the other answers have explained in more detail:

> "The girl **was** led through the gates of the city."
> *Puella per portās urbis ducta **est**.*

In both languages the verb is composed of two parts.
You can't drop the "was" from the English version; "led" alone is not enough.
You can't drop the *est* from the Latin version; *ducta* alone is not enough.
The reason for adding *est* is the same as the one for adding "was".

In this instance Latin and English work similarly, but in many other situations the similarity disappears entirely.
This happens, for example, if you transform the story to the present tense: "is led" corresponds to *ducitur*.

The *est* can be left implicit in some cases.
Even if not written, it is still thought to be there.
This is a peculiarity of Latin not present in English; including forms of "to be" is not optional.
But in a simple passive clause like this one the verb *est* is included virtually without exception, so it arguably belongs in your sentence.

Comment: Genuinely curious: do you know of any examples where the *est* is left implicit in a passive construction like this? The "est" stops me from reading it as a participial phrase. If I saw, "frater ab hoste occisus," I can't help reading it as incomplete: "My brother, who was killed by the enemy, ...."

Comment: @brianpck Good question! That has been extremely rare in my experience, limited to uses where succinctness is a stylistic choice. I gave the wrong impression in the answer; I'll try to retone it.

Comment: @brianpck  These examples are not typical but can sometimes be found. Cf. the first sentence in https://latin.packhum.org/loc/684/2/82#82 As for subordination contexts, the omission of the copula in passive constructions is probably even less typical but can also be found: e.g., cf. https://latin.packhum.org/loc/690/3/0/23956-23972#0

Comment: Given the **different** copulas you've put in bold (Engl. **was** / Lat. **est**), I imagine that some beginners could wonder about the reason of this difference. In fact, it is quite probable that this point is the source of OP's question (the OP does not seem to understand the role of _est_ (PP) in a construction that is translated as _was_ (PP)). As for your interesting comment/reply to brianpck above, it could also be a good idea to advise the learners of Latin that the copula is more frequently omitted in infinitival subordinate clauses (_puellam per portās urbis ductam_ (_esse_)).

Comment: @Mitomino True, the difference in copulas can cause confusion. I interpreted the question here as asking why a copula is there in the first place, so I took a simple approach to just that. The way I see it, the difference in tense is due to the English *led* being effectively a present passive participle but *ducta* being a past passive participle. I can't make sense of English passive syntax unless I allow the passive participles to be of the present tense at times. Perhaps this is due to Finnish having both past and present participles for both active and passive voice.

Answer (score 8):

If you speak languages other than English, it is even easier to see why *est* is necessary, when the translation can be exactly parallel:

> verbum est ductum de... = "(het) woord **is afgeleid** van..." [Dutch]
> verbum est ductum de... = "(le) mot **est dérivé** de..." [French]

Comment: An orthogonal point on your "particularly chosen" examples (the ones in bold): in order to preserve the exact typological parallelism with the Dutch form _**af**geleid_ (cf. also the lexicalized form in Fr. _dé-rivé_), one would expect to find this prefix in Latin as well (_**de**ductum_).

Comment: @Mitomino: Indeed! Though then one no longer exactly has the participle *duct-* from the Question. To be quite honest, I mainly posted this answer because it was funny to have all moderators post somewhat equal answers.

Comment: Yes, as noted/acknowledged, my comment above was orthogonal to the question at issue but, to tell you the truth, I couldn't help raising this point because of the very important typological parallelism between Latin and Germanic languages (cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11083/are-latin-verbs-of-motion-satellite-framed-or-verb-framed ).

Comment: @Mitomino: Noted, though I think that terminology is somewhat odd. I would rather say something like 'radical and extraradical directionality of verbs'? Then there is the matter of defining roots which is important...

Comment: Yes, you're right. Talmy's (1991, 2000) famous terminology (verb-framed vs. satellite-framed languages) is not only, as you say, "somewhat odd" but, what is worse, _can_ be quite misleading when dealing with Latin (or Slavic languages). However, his terminology is, _nolens volens_, the one that is by far (!) more widespread in the linguistic literature.

Comment: Turning back to the issue, I was wondering if your two examples will be clear enough for the OP to understand what you mean: the two examples you've selected can (also) be interpreted as involving an **adjectival** passive, right? (cf. the OP's example, which _clearly/only_ involves a **verbal** passive). In order to clarify this issue, perhaps you could deal with the difference in English between "This word is derived from..." & "This word {was/has been} derived from..."  and its connection with the potential ambiguity of _verbum est (de)ductum de_...  (its adjectival and verbal readings).

Comment: Cf. _Caesar mortuus est_ and/or _Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres_, which are, in principle, ambiguous between two readings: 'Caesar is dead' (adjectival reading) & 'Caesar died' (verbal reading); 'all Gaul is divided...' (adjectival reading; the preferred one here) & 'all Gaul {has been/was} divided...' (verbal reading). For related discussion, see  https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8815/on-the-typical-ambiguity-of-porta-clausa-est  E.g., cf. the verbal passive _porta {clauditur/ **clausa est** } a Gaio_ with the adjectival passive _porta **clausa**  {**est** /fuit} (??a Gaio_).

Answer (score 6):

> If I translated the sentence without 'est', it would be "The girl was led through the gates of the city", right?

Actually, this part isn't correct. Without the *est*, it's missing the verb and you are left only with an adjective:

> "the girl, having been led through the gates of the city..."

The whole form is *ducta est*. The perfect passive tenses have a form of *sum* in their conjugation.

- I was led -> *ductus sum*
- He was led -> *ductus est*
- She was led -> *ducta est*

Etc.

The same is true for the passives of the pluperfect (*ductus eram*) and future perfect (*ductus ero*) tenses.

Comment: It can be helpful to think of *ductus* as 'having-been-led' in English, so 'I am having-been-led' for 'I was led'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129128/discussion-on-answer-by-cmw-why-is-est-added-to-the-end-of-this-sentence).

Comment: @dbmag9 I often find that it's very helpful to "rationalize" concepts from other languages in the way you just described. It helps me bridge the mental gap between how I express ideas and how a native speaker might express similar ideas.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that *ducta*, on its own, is a participle. It comes from *ducere*, but it acts as an **adjective** "led", not as a verb "lead".

In Latin, there are no finite verb forms for the perfect tense passive. The language just doesn't have them. So to indicate this meaning, Latin-speakers used *periphrastic* or *compound* forms: they had a perfect passive *participle*, so they combined that with forms of *sum* to get a finite perfect passive meaning. "Led" as an adjective is *ducta*, and so "she was led" as a verb is *ducta est*.

English, in fact, does the same thing for all of its passives. English doesn't have any finite verb forms for the passive voice, but *does* have a passive participle, so we just combine that participle with forms of "be" to get passive finite meaning: "is led", "was led", "will be led". The difference is that English has to do this for *all* its passives, while Latin only needs it in the perfect (and pluperfect and future perfect).

At its core, though, *ducta* still acts like an adjective. That's why it marks gender and case, which finite verbs don't: she *ducta est* but he *ductus est* and it *ductum est*. Very literally, "she is (*est*) in a state of having been led (*ducta*)".

…and, just because this wasn't confusing enough, Latin actually adds one more complication on here. In Latin in general, forms of *sum* can generally be dropped if they're clear from the context. Which means you **could** actually form this sentence without the *est*! But it's important to remember that the *est* **should** be there, even if it's just implied and not spoken: the sentence needs a finite verb, and *ducta* is a participle, not a finite form.

Comment: A minor comment on your following statement, which, I think, is correct but can be qualified: "you could actually form this sentence (sc. _Puella per portās urbis ducta est_) without the est". As pointed out in the comments in Joonas's answer, it seems that the omission of the copula in finite forms of passive constructions is not as typical as one could expect. Philologically speaking, it may also have some interest to study why this omission in this particular context is more typical in Varro, Vergil, Livy or Tacitus but much less so in Cicero.

Comment: @Mitomino: A simple answer might be: highly stylised, and metrically influenced, language tends to take more liberties with standard syntax?

Comment: @Cerberus Yes, I tend to agree with you. However, concerning this phenomenon, the notion of "highly stylised" should be made more precise. It seems that the omission of finite forms of auxiliary _esse_ becomes more frequent from Livy onwards. I'm not sure if that change is just a matter of stylistics.

Comment: Draconis, it seems to me that your literal paraphrase of OP's example is very adequate: "she is (_est_) in a state of having been led (_ducta_)" (sc. by someone). This non-ambiguous example can be compared with the famous one _Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres_, which is, in principle, ambiguous between two readings: 'all Gaul is divided...' ("adjectival passive" reading; the preferred one; cf. past: _fuit divisa_) & 'all Gaul {has been/was} divided...' ("verbal passive" reading; cf. present: _dividitur_).  Would you then give different paraphrases/analyses for each of these two readings?

Comment: @Mitomino "Is divided" vs "has been divided" seems like it captures the adjectival/verbal distinction well there, because "divided" is common adjectivally in English ("divided highway") and isn't common in the present passive. But I don't know of a good general way to translate that distinction, because "is ---ed" can also be present passive with a verbal meaning ("is led" for example sounds verbal rather than adjectival to me).

Comment: From your interesting and indeed appropriate paraphrase above of OP's example, I'd expect that perhaps you'd assign these two different paraphrases to Caesar's famous example: 1) the adjectival passive reading (the preferred one): 'all Gaul is in a state of divided" and 2) the verbal passive reading: 'all Gaul is in a state of having been divided' (sc. by someone).  As you probably already know, in Spanish this distinction is more transparently captured by the _estar/ser_ copular alternation: cf. "La Galia {está dividida (adjectival passive)/ha sido dividida (verbal passive)}".

Comment: @Mitomino The problem there is that "in a state of divided" doesn't sound grammatical to me; I'd say "in a state of division" which only works when the verb has a convenient derived noun.

Comment: The informal semantic paraphrases aren't intended to sound natural (nor even grammatical) but to capture the abstract meanings involved. Adjectival passive = Gallia DIVISA est, where the state of 'divided' does not contain the agentivity layer. In contrast, verbal passive = Gallia DIVISA est, where the state of 'divided' does include causativity/agentivity. Crucially, a state 'divided' is involved in both cases, i.e. in both cases we have a participle (as you say, an "adjective") but the "verbal passive" one is more complex. NB: the category of Aspect can be understood as a stativizer.