# What is the Latin verb for "To move out, or cause to be moved out, upon, or by means of, rollers or small wheels"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What is the Latin verb for "To move out, or cause to be moved out, upon, or by means of, rollers or small wheels"? I tried hard to find something like this on the Internet, but I failed...

evolve/revolve? No. It means to roll something. Like a stone.

*E.g.* Mar 16:3 *et dicebant ad invicem quis revolvet nobis lapidem ab ostio monumenti* 
**He wheeled out a stretcher from the ambulance. - E subitis medicae curru lecticulam evolvi.**

It looks like the poor paramedic rolled it out in the head over heels way, doesn't it?

I know it's better to say *He unloaded a stretcher from the ambulance*. Though what word is for unload in Latin in the case? exonero? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if there's a specific word for "move by wheels" -- [Latin tends to express manner of motion not in the verb itself, but by adverbials, participles, and the like](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11083/are-latin-verbs-of-motion-satellite-framed-or-verb-framed).

So you might want to use a verb like *traho* "drag, pull" (or some prefixed variant like *abstraho, extraho*), and add something like *rotis* "by wheels" if necessary.